# How to create a sql query in SFMC with where clause with date and time

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, datetime, database, data-views

I am trying to create a query that pulls the record from _open data view before a specific date and time, how to do that in sql?

I am currently doing this for defining the date:

```
Select * from _open where case(eventDate as date) <= '2023-01-30' /*yyyy-mm-dd*/
```

**Goal: I would like to get results before Jan 30 5:30pm**

**Question: How to define date and time in the sql query?**

I am not sure if this is the right way?

```
Select * from _open where case(eventDate as date) <= '2023-01-30 17:30:00.000' /*yyyy-mm-dd*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple like this

```
Select 
*
from _Open 
where EventDate <= '2023-01-30 17:30:00.000'
```

Only one note that `_Open` data view records dating back six months from the day the query runs are available.

Comment: Hi Duc Lee thank you for your response. Does that mean I do not have to convert the date string into time or anything? simply using '2023-01-30 17:30:00.000' will work?

Comment: @kl2 no need. The data type for EventDate is already datetime type https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5